# Making JS request to my Rails API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, api, rails-api

I am new to rails. 
I am creating a basic rails-api. Trying to add user to my model using JS request ...

Here is my HTML file: (add-user.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $('#adduser').submit(function(e){
            $.post('http://localhost:3000/users', {user: {username: $("#usr").value}, user: {password:$("#psw").value}});
    });
    });
</script>

<form id="adduser" data-ajax="false">
<input type="text" id="usr" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="psw"  placeholder="Password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add User" id="usradd" name="login"/>
</form>
```

When I click on submit, $.post() simply adds the data to my url ...
The data is not added to my model ...

My users_controller code:

```
def new
   @user = User.new
   render json: @user
end

def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

if @user.save
  render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
else
  render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you dont need to use $.post as you can submit the form by specifying action url in the form tag itself. Please do check the following.

> `<form action="/users/create" method="post">
>         <input type="text" id="usr" placeholder="Username"/>
>         <input type="password" id="psw"  placeholder="Password"/>
>         <input type="button" value="Add User" id="usradd" name="login"/>
>   </form>`

Comment: Hi @sufinsha ... It worked but null values are added to my model ... Hence i made following changes which worked like <form action="/users/create" method="post"> ... but following code also adds null values to my model ...

    $('#usradd').click(function (e) {
    var user = {
    username: $("#usrname").val(),
    password: $("#pswd").val()
    };
    $.post('/users/create',user);}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="usr" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="psw"  placeholder="Password"/>
<input type="button" value="Add User" id="usradd" name="login"/>

$(function () {
    $('#usradd').click(function(e){
        var user = {
            username: $("#usr").val(),
            password: $("#psw").val()
        }
        $.post('/users/create', user);
    });
 });
```

'/users/create' - i think it should look like this, but it depends on your routs settings. To find out it use rake:routes command.

**Edit:**

You don't really need form element in this case.

**Edit #2:**
If you need redirect after the user was created, you don't need ajax at all.  You should use form_for rails helper which will help you to build a form for your user model. You don't need any javascript code in this case.

Comment: It still didn't work .... 
I've kept a default route that matches all possible cases i.e. 
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

After adding the above code my it goes to "http://localhost:3000/add-user.html?login=Add+User"

Also I tried putting this code in index.html ... Here it doesn't redirect anywhere ... stays on the same page ...

Comment: Of course it will no redirect, it's ajax, not bostback! You should add .done(function(data) { /*callback body*/ }) to $.post as a parameter. In data you will see you new page, or json object (depends on what your controller method returns). Then you can either redirect to the page you need or update a part of a page using html from response.

Answer (score 0):

Yauhen's answer should do the trick. I realize that you were probably just trying to get this to work, but wanted to point out that you want to avoid using the full url in a post request like this. Its not necessary, and will potentially introduce bigger issues as you migrate your code to staging and production regions.